# MVC check Email already exists or not using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is first time i implement something like this :) please easy on me :) i did my research but i still have some problem to get this work. I have page where i can create user and i also want to check user email already exists or not.

This is what i did, but i still can create user with same email over and over again. Can anyone please help me or point me in to the right direction!
Thanks in advance :)

Model:

```
 public class A_S_PX2
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       [Remote("AddCustomer", "User", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "User with this Email already exists")]
       public string Email_ID { get; set; }
    }
```

View Model :

```
public class user
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddCustomer(user model , string Mail)
    {

        var u = db.PX2.Where(a => a.Id == model.ID && a.Email_ID.Equals(Mail, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (u == null)
        {
            db.PX2.Add(new A_S_PX2 { Email_ID = Mail});
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        else
        {
            return Json("Email already exists", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddUser()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
  @Html.ValidationSummary()

  <form id="CreateCustomer">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>E-mail</label>
         <input type="email"  class="form-control mail">
      </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" value="Send" id="BtnOpretKundeJS" class="btn">
    </div>

  </form>

$(function () {

    $("#BtnOpretKundeJS").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var model = {
            Mail: $(".mail").val(),
        }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("AddCustomer")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    Mail: model.Mail
                },
                success: function (run) {
                    console.log('Ok');
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                }
       });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: The `a.Id == model.ID` in your WHERE clause, is that correct ? What if you try `a.Id != model.ID` ?

Comment: @Shyju Sorry  i forgot to add my ViewModel , i updated my question , i binded with ViewModel :)

Comment: `model.ID` is going to be `0` when you create a new record. rite ? So your `u` will be always `null`. Read my first comment for a possible fix. If you do not quite follow, just remove `a.Id == model.ID` from your LINQ expression and see what happens.

Comment: @Shyju yes i tried with this but still can create user with same email : db.PX2.Where(a => a.Id != model.ID && a.Email_ID.Equals(Mail, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: So `u` is still null ? In that case, is your `Id` column unique ?

Comment: @Shyju  yes and yes ... i just debugged

Comment: What is the Id of the record which exist(for the email you are trying) and what is the value of `model.ID` in your `AddCustomer` method ?

Comment: If you switch to `a => a.Id != model.ID`, your code should work. fine.

Comment: I did as you Said :  db.PX2.Where(a => a.Id != model.ID && a.Email_ID.Equals(Mail, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault(); but its still same i Can create user w same e-mail

Comment: Value of Model.ID is 0

Comment: Tried your code locally and it works 100%

Comment: Would you please posted , where i Can see it , maybe i miss something

Comment: It is the same code as your question (except the `a.Id != model.ID` part)

Comment: @Shyju yes its working now :) but it cant display msg. can i make dat happend in my Ajax for displaying MSG?

Comment: replace `console.log('Ok');` with `alert('ok;)`

Comment: @Shyju i mean dat msg it should be displayd if Email already exists or not.

Comment: @Shyju and i also checked i dont bind email with viewmodel , i pass dat with paramerters and i think beacuse of dat validation msg and remote not going to work for me , therefor maybe i should implement to display msg in client side

Comment: How did you fix your first problem ?

Comment: @Shyju as you told me a.Id != model.ID and i checked my DB its not coming new record if i enter same email is already exists

Comment: @Shyju anyway thanks for help :)